# Deleting a node at nth position in a linked list in C++ ------ Last number is not getting deleted

Tags: c++, linked-list

On running this code, when I enter n as 4, the program stops instead of getting output as 2 4 6
I cant delete the last node in this linked list.
it works fine for all other position but not for the last node. Is it because the there is no (n+1)th node after the last node to which the (n-1)th node should point. and should I add some more code in the delete function explicitly to delete the last node?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head;
void Insert(int data, int n)
{
    struct Node* temp1 = new Node();
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(n == 1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    
    }
    struct Node* temp2 = head;
    for(int i = 0; i<n-2; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    temp1->next =temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
}
void Print()
{
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void Delete(int n)
{
    struct Node* temp1 = head;
    if(n == 1)
    {
       head = temp1->next;
       free(temp1);
       return;
    }
int i;
    for(i = 0; i<n-2; i++)
      {
         temp1 = temp1->next; 
         struct Node* temp2 = temp1->next;
         temp1->next = temp2->next;
         free(temp2);
      }
  }
int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    Insert(2, 1);
    Insert(4,2);
    Insert(6,3);
    Insert(5,4);
    Print(); 
    int n;
    printf("Enter a position\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    Delete(n);
    Print();
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking about their differences.

Comment: `temp2 = temp2->next;` You never check if `temp2` is valid or if you run beyond the limits of your list.

Comment: It's not just the last element. What if I want the second element? `for(i=0;i<0;...)` that loop in Delete won't do anything for n=2. Take a moment to think about what you should be doing. Then implement that.

Comment: Your deletion loop is supposed to remove one node, but calls `free` n-2 times.

Comment: In `Delete` you `free` all nodes except for `head`. I assume you only want to free the last one.

Comment: Work out what's supposed to happen first, drawing lists and nodes with pen(cil) and paper. Then translate into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to do a little more work on your delete algorithm. If you expand your test case to more than 4 nodes, I think you'll discover that there are more issues than just deleting the last node. I rewrote your delete function while trying to keep some of your same logic.

The comments mention some of your issues, but it looks like your for-loop calls free n-2 times. That's not what we want. We use the loop to "find" the node we want to delete, and then call free once (after reassigning the proper pointers)

```
void Delete(int n){
    struct Node* temp1 = head;
    if(n == 1)
    {
        head = temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
    }

    // Find the node right before the one you want to delete. 
    for(int i = 0; i<n-2; i++){
         temp1 = temp1->next; 
    }

    struct Node* node_to_be_deleted = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = node_to_be_deleted->next;

    free(node_to_be_deleted);
}
```

note: There's no error checking here...